# My HTML5 Video Player is not working when I install PWA in iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, html5-video, progressive-web-apps

Hello I made a PWA that plays random videos. It works perfectly fine in Android or PC and almost perfect in Safari but when I install the app in iOS my HTML5 video player does not load the videos. It was working 2 days ago and nothing big changed since back then but today it's not working. Also because I don't have any MacOS devices to run the simulator on so I can't debug it. I have the source code open in GitHub, do you have any idea what this is all about?

I am also giving the video source with JS, if that has something to do with it.

```
document.getElementById("vsrc").src = srcRaw + videoid + ".mp4";
document.getElementById("videoEl").load();
```

GitHub code: https://github.com/ondersumer07/vinematik

Site itself: https://ondersumer07.github.io/vinematik/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research I figured it out. What you need to do is add `crossorigin` attribute to your HTML5 `video` element. But it needs to be only in iOS otherwise it will break your video player on Android or Web.

To do that you need to use a bit of javascript:

```
// Detect iOS and if it is, add the crossorigin to the video player so that it is working as expected
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mac') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1){
    document.getElementById("videoEl").setAttribute("crossorigin", "true");
};
```

This piece of code will add `crossorigin` attribute to `video` element only in iOS. And when you use that code it also works in PWA.

This is how I solved my problem.

Comment: Is this still working? I'm trying a react app and not seeing this work...

Comment: Yes, right now it's still working. Hope this helps you :)